# Is this the right way of testing a pandas dataframe in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-unittest

I have a function which returns a dataframe which has rows and columns.
here's the function: app.py

```
def pandas_factory(colnames, rows):
    return pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=colnames)
```

And here is my unit testcase for the same: test_app.py

```
    def test_panda_fact(self):
        from dlp.dlp import pandas_factory
        df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]})
        with pytest.raises(TypeError) as er:
            mock_open = mock.mock_open(read_data=df1)
            with patch('dlp.dlp.pandas_factory', mock_open):
                obj = pandas_factory
            self.assertTrue(obj)
```

The testcase runs but am I testing it in the right way?

Comment: What is the point of the first test? You are not actually using `pandas_factory()` to create dataframes so what exactly is it you're trying to test here? Also, hard-coding test cases is generally not a great idea.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do in the remaining test?

Comment: @pavel yes I figured that. please check the updated question

Comment: I created a new dataframe and im trying to patch it

Comment: What is `self.assertTrue()` here?

Comment: @pavel just checking whether the object being called is true or not

Comment: I don't think it's a correct way of testing and I don't think you need a test here. What exactly do you think you need to test? The fact that `pandas.DataFrame` does what it is supposed to do? Or the fact that `pandas_factory` object exists?

Comment: If you want to test something you probably need to test that the object that `pandas_factory` returns is a pandas dataframe and that the shape of dataframe is `(rows, len(colnames))`.

Comment: @pavel The fact that pandas_factory object exists.

Comment: @pavel could you please show me how its done?

Comment: You create an object by importing it at the start of your test function. If it didn't exist the import would fail. This test will always pass or hit an exception **before** getting to assertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's an example of how I would go about testing this function:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np

from dlp.dlp import pandas_factory

def test_type():
    df1 = pandas_factory(rows=np.array([[1, 2],[3, 4]]), colnames=['a', 'b'])
    assert isinstance(df1, pandas.core.frame.DataFrame)

def test_size():
    cols = np.random.randint(10, 100)
    length = np.random.randint(10, 100)
    data = np.zeros((length, cols))

    df = pandas_factory(rows=data, colnames=[str(i) for i in range(cols)])
    assert df.shape == (length, cols)
```

Something along those lines. Here I'm assuming that `rows` is some form of data, like a numpy array.